# Error including manually installed TikZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, installing

I am trying to manually install tikz in my local texmf tree on my shell account at school.

I simply unpacked the latest build to ~/texmf/tex and ran texhash.

Now, trying to compile this simple document gives me an error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 TEST TEST TEST
\end{document}
```

And the error is:

```
! Missing { inserted.

                   r
l.394 \pgfutil@setuppdfresources
                                 % possibly call the above
? x
```

Anyone seen anything like this before?

**Edit:**
OK, this actually compiles fine in latex, but not in pdflatex (which is preferable to me so I can include raster graphic formats).

Here is the log file from the failing pdflatex run (kind of long to post here): http://gaia.ecs.csus.edu/~winteren/test.log

**Edit 2:**
Ok, still not working after removing the old pgf installation and installing the newest version from sourceforge. Looks pretty much the same, but here's the new failing log file: http://gaia.ecs.csus.edu/~winteren/test2.log

Comment: I believe that you also need the `pgf` package.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I was under the impression that PGF and TikZ were packaged together. This is what I downloaded: http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/

Comment: @nw.: You minimal example does compile without a problem. Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass[..]{...}`. Then, extract the everything after `*File List*` in your `.log` file and add it to your post by editing it. That's the best way one can assess what's going on.

Comment: Try to inspect your example's log file. It contains every single file which has been loaded. I would suspect that you will see TWO different versions of tikz; some of your new installation and some of the old one. If so, I would recommend using `export TEXINPUTS=~/mytikz//:` and unpack tikz as-is to `~/mytikz`. The `TEXINPUTS` variable has higher priority than `~/texmf` (I assume you have unix).

Comment: @Werner, edited with full log file. I also figured out that it compiles fine in latex, but errors in pdflatex only. Weird.

Comment: The reason that there is an error with pdflatex but not latex is because the problem is contained in a driver component which is different for different engines, so there is a file that pdflatex loads which latex doesn't.  That version of PGF looks old to me (I'm on a slow connection so haven't yet verified that).  Try getting the latest version from sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/ I know it might be irritating to have to reinstall it, but since you want a newer version than that on your system you may as well use the most up to date.

Comment: Looking at your log file, it does appear to be using the version from your texmf directory so you've installed it correctly.  But you should upgrade to the latest version and try again.  If it still doesn't work, update the question to say so.

Comment: Did you figure out what's going on here?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Unfortunately, no. I finally got around to reinstalling pgf this week (been busy with exams), and it is failing with the same errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: The errors in the log point to particular lines in the code which are somewhat opaque to me.  I'll ask in chat to see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: The suspicion from the experts is that your pdftex installation is very, very old.  On my machine, when I run `pdflatex -v` then the first line is `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)`.  What do you get?

Comment: pdfTeX (Web2C 7.4.5) 3.14159-1.10b

Comment: My informants tell me that that dates from 2002/3.  It's quite possible that some code has been improved since then and that TikZ/PGF relies on the newer code.  Do you have access to a later version of TeX that you can test your document with?  (Could you install TeXLive 2011 in your local directory?)  If your version of TeX really is 8 or 9 years old then you may have more problems than just with TikZ!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll have to check on my disk space quota to see if this will be possible. Worst case scenario I ssh to my home computer for compiling my latex documents.

Comment: Any chance you can get your school to upgrade?  That really is old software and installing TL2011 system-wide wouldn't be difficult.  (Incidentally, if you prefix your comments by `@username` then `username` gets notified of the comment.).  If not, it isn't necessary to install all of TL2011, maybe just the binaries will be enough for you.

Comment: I'm beginning to feel that this question doesn't really have an answer other than "You need a newer version of pdftex".  So partly to remove it from the "unanswered" list, I'd like to recommend that it be closed as "too localised".  Would that be okay?  It will still be possible to comment (though it might be easier in chat), and if you have follow-up questions then they'd be welcome.  Does that sound okay?

Comment: @AndrewStacey, Yes, that would be fine.